# Kinessis Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, amazon-kinesis

I am working on a POC for sending data from Kinesis to Kafka using AWS Kinesis connector available with Confluent. I am using trial version of the connector valid for 30 days.

I keep getting below error on the connector. The connection to AWS S3 is fine from the same server. So i don't believe issue is with any missing certificate. But below is the error i keep getting.

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed::
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valii
d certification path to requested target
```

Sorry for not providing version information. 
Confluent Community 5.5 version has been used to setup connector. It is running on 1 Docker container for now. I am starting connect-distributed with connect-distributed.properties file. The Apache Open source Kafka is running on 3 nodes. Version of Kafka is 2.3.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide more details of how you are running this connector? How have you installed the components, what versions, and what config are you using for the connector?

Comment: sorry for not providing enough information. I have added version information now.

Comment: The issue was due to missing certificate itself. Using right truststore fixed the issue